# Stored procedure returning wrong decimal point

Tags: c#, java, sql, stored-procedures, aspxgridview

Hello i have a PropertiesComboBox which i use for filtering and i am populating it using a stored procedure. However when the values are returned in the PropertiesComboBox, they are returned with extra 0's. It returns 3.0000 when i only want it to return 3.00

Here is my code for the stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROC GetPromoValueColumn @Platform varchar(30)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT      p.Value
    FROM        PromotionalCode p
    JOIN        Application a
    ON          a.ID = p.AppID
    GROUP BY    p.Value
END
```

Any idea as to why this happens?

thanks.

Comment: That's not a problem. technically both are same use `yourDecimal.ToString("0.00");` to format it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

p.Value is of a precision that would allow for values with 4 places after the decimal point.

Mathematically, 3, 3.0, 3.00, 3.000, 3.0000 and 3.00000 are the same value: 3.

It's entirely up to you to format it in a way that makes sense for your application.

Comment: Ok, how would i format it so that it rounds the values to 2 decimal points?

Thanks

Comment: You can use a [custom numeric format string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8(v=vs.110).aspx) to format your value to whatever you want.

Comment: You can use this in c# like Convert.Todouble(value).Tostring("#0.00")

Answer (score 0):

Probably you defined your PromotionalCode.p field as decimal(X,4)

X rapresent the total number of digits of your number, 4 is the number of decimal digits.
If you try to redefine your table column as decimal(X,2) you will see only 2 decimals digits.

es:

```
ALTER TABLE PromotionalCode MODIFY COLUMN p DECIMAL(10,2) DEFAULT NULL;
```

Comment: i dont want to alter the table, is there a way of altering the stored procedure for the same result?

Comment: In mySQL SELECT CAST(p.Value AS DECIMAL(10,2))

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @id decimal(16,3)
```

you need to set the decimal values as per your requirement